# Можно ли сеарилизовать и зашифровать ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, криптография

Пишу простое приложение на Android. Имеется `ArrayList`  с объектами моего класса.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователь получал доступ к списку, когда введёт пароль, а файл должен храниться в зашифрованном виде в устройстве.
Я только разбираюсь в Java и прошу не кидаться тапками. Пока функции для шифрования и дешифрования выглядят так. Шифрует без проблем, при дешифровке выдает `IOException null`. Объясните пожалуйста, в чём проблема.

```
public void encryptData() {
    TextView debug = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DebugMessages);
    password = "Pass";

    byte[] iv = "Initializing vector".getBytes();
    byte[] pass = password.getBytes();
    //создаём пароль и инициализирующий вектор
    try {

        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        pass = sha.digest(pass);
        pass = Arrays.copyOf(pass, 16);

        iv = sha.digest(iv);
        iv = Arrays.copyOf(iv, 16);

        //Задаём ключ и инициализирующий вектор 

        Key key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(pass, "AES/CBC/NoPadding");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));


        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput("Encrypted.data", MODE_PRIVATE));
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);

        oos.writeObject(mas); 

        debug.setText("Вроде зашифровано");
    }catch (Exception e){debug.setText(e.getMessage());}
}

public void decryptData() {
    password = "Pass";
    byte[] iv = "Initializing vector".getBytes();
    byte[] pass = password.getBytes();
    TextView debug = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DebugMessages);

    try {

        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        pass = sha.digest(pass);
        pass = Arrays.copyOf(pass, 16);


        iv = sha.digest(iv);
        iv = Arrays.copyOf(iv, 16);

        Key key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(pass, "AES/CBC/NoPadding");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(openFileInput("Encrypted.data"));
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);


        mas = (ArrayList)ois.readObject(); //получаем наш список


    }catch(Exception e){debug.setText(e.getMessage());}
}
```

Comment: Если вы приведете полный stacktrace ошибки - разобраться будет намного легче

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю, как привести stacktrace, я даже для сообщений использую TextView на устройстве

Comment: Жесть. Почитайте про [LogTag](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) (facepalm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо закрывать выходной поток после окончания шифрования.

Замечания по коду:

1. По хорошему енкриптору и декриптору надо передавать сгенерированный ключ и вектор
2. Процесс генерации ключа и вектора вынести в отдельные методы. Причем вектор надо генерировать при первом обращении случайно и писать результат в преференсах
3. Предусмотреть процесс соления пароля с сохранием/чтением соли в преференсах (отдельно от преференсов вектора)
4. Алгоритм выравнивания блоков `noPadding` нельзя использовать с модой `CBC` - рекомендуется `PKCS`

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю

Comment: А вы поняли где ошибка то? Я имею ввиду, что вы не закрываете поток после окончания шифрования - в итоге у вас оказывается неполный (или что скорее всего пустой)

Comment: Понял, исправил, и NoPadding заменил на PKCS5, заработало.

Comment: И про LogTag обязательно почитаю, просто в Android Studio работаю только вторую неделю))